# redirection from one controller to another in rhodes mobile application frame work using ruby

Tags: ruby, redirect, controller, rhodes

i like share this to programmers who are new in rhodes frame work. I got one problem in redirecting from one controller to another. First time i tried below code.

redirect_to :controller => :User, :action=>:new

But wasn't working for me. I got below soln for that and it works fine.

url_for :controller => :User, :action=>:new

Thanks, 
Dileep Paul

Answer (score 1):

In Rhodes, the proper syntax is `redirect`, not `redirect_to`.  (reference: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom#associations)

You also do not need to utilize the `url_for` construct.

```
def create
     @product = Product.new(@params['product'])
     @product.save

     redirect :controller => :Customer, :action => :index
end
```